# Se souvenir/se rappeler et la préposition

Tags: usage, prépositions

Deux interrogations, à propos de l'usage de se rappeler/se souvenir.

Normalement, on utilise la préposition "de" seulement avec "Se souvenir".

> Je me souviens de cet été-là, tu avais perdu ta dent de lait.
>
> Je me rappelle les vacances au bord de la mer, j'avais 6 ou 7 ans.

Et non <strike>Je me rappelle **des** vacances au bord de la mer.</strike>

Moi, j'ai tendance, pourtant, à dire couramment "Je me rappelle du voyage en Hongrie", ça continue à me sembler tellement naturel, que je fais tout le temps la faute. Je me demande si c'est une règle ancienne, ou si c'est depuis lors rentré dans le langage, sous la plume de nombreux écrivains?

Sources:

- http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/dictee/2017/03/25/37005-20170325ARTFIG00004-se-rappeler-de-ne-faites-plus-la-faute.php
- https://www.frantastique.com/fr/regles-orthographe/se-souvenir-et-se-rappeler

Par contre, avec le pronom personnel (pronom non neutre), la règle devient:

> Je me rappelle d'elle.
>
> Et non, je me la rappelle.

**Pourquoi?** Depuis quand cette règle est-elle utilisée, et qu'est-ce qui nous vaut cette exception?

Pour l'utilisation du neutre, on dirait:
Je m'en rappelle. (Je me rappelle de cette époque de ma vie.)
Je me la rappelle. (Je me rappelle de la beauté de la ville.) Plus rare et littéraire.

Il y a aussi la particularité de ce verbe de pouvoir s'employer avec "à".

> Je me rappelle à tes bons souvenirs.

--- Le verbe souvenir, différences ---

Par contre, ce verbe-ci, s'utilise toujours avec *de*, pour les non-neutres.

> Je me souviens de lui.

Pour le neutre, il s'emploie comme *Souvenir*.
Neutre: Je m'en souviens (ces vacances).

**Pourquoi cela?**

Au niveau du sens, je me rappelle ces vacances, et je me souviens de ces vacances, semblent pratiquement interchangeables, dans ce contexte-là, où on n'a justement pas de contexte.

Bien que *se souvenir* ait souvent un tour un peu plus nostalgique que *se rappeler*.

> Je me rappelle d'avoir appelé le dentiste.
> Je me souviens de mon premier été.

Ce n'est pas aussi tranché que cela dans la pratique, mais il y a une connotation différente pour les deux verbes.

Plus d'informations sur l'usage et l'historique de ces 2 mots, et de l'usage de "de" sont bienvenus, en supplément de la réponse que j'attends à mes deux questions.

Comment: Il me semble que l'on dise plutôt « Je me rappelle d'avoir appelé le dentiste.» . L'infinitif tout simple ne spécifie pas une action : - Nous regrettons d'avoir vendu notre voiture. « Je me rappelle d'approvisionner mon compte. », par exemple, exprime les actions habituelles d'approvisionnement, mais aucune  de celles-ci  en particulier.

Comment: Effectivement, sous cette forme, cela signifie plutôt :" il faut bien que je me rappelle d'appeler le dentiste".

Answer (score 3):

Principalement, ce meli-melo de citations ignore une distinction plus courante.  Se rappeler de quelque chose marche, oui (je me rappelle de mes premieres vacances en Bretagne).  Mais on peut aussi se rappeler que quelque chose existe (je me rappelle qu'elle n'aime pas le chocolat) ou se passe (elle se rappelle que c'est Jean qui a ferme la porte).  Et finalement on rappelle quelque chose a quelqu'un quand on a besoin qu'il le fasse (je lui ais rappele qu'il avait rendez vous demain, rappelle-toi qu'il faut amener ton certificat).

Se souvenir de quelque chose n'a d'equivalence qu'a la premiere fonction.  En gros, le souvenir est plus passif, le rappel implique un certain effort.

Answer (score 1):

**I** 
Se rappeler

**1/**

> (TLFi) Empl. pronom. Qqn se rappelle qqc./qqn. Avoir, garder, se remettre en mémoire. Synon. se souvenir de

> (TLFi) qqc [Le verbe exprime un état] Avoir présent à l'esprit, avoir en mémoire quelque chose; garder le souvenir de quelque chose.

- Elle se rappelait son enfance dans beaucoup de détail, n'y voyait jamais que des jours heureux. (user **LPH**)

> (TLFi) qqc  [Le verbe exprime une action] Se remettre en mémoire; faire resurgir, retrouver le souvenir de quelque chose. Synon. se remémorer.

- Quand elle se rappelait son enfance, elle ne pouvait penser qu'à des jours heureux. (user **LPH**)

Les deux contextes qui viennent d'être illustrés montrent une différence difficile entre deux sens du verbe, le premier sens  étant du type qui **exprime un état** alors que le second est du type bien différent qui **exprime une action**. C'est une différence qui ne se fait pas toujours automatiquement et qui, avant que le locuteur soit assez familier avec la langue française, necessite parfois de sa part une certaine réflexion. Les indices qui permettent une reconnaissance sure et rapide du sens sont les mots particuliers qui accompagnent le verbe et ausssi le contexte, mais tout cela constitue  véritablement une  petite théorie, malheureusement. Par exemple, selon le contexte une même forme peut avoir les deux sens;

- Il lui arrivait de se rappeler son enfance et elle était vite prise de crises d'horreur, mais la plupart du temps les faits qui étaient évoqués à propos de sa vie d'enfant ne lui disaient rien et n'avaient pas d'effet, comme si sa mémoire ne fontionnait plus. (personne schizophrénique, user **LPH**)
- Il lui arrivait de se rappeler son enfance et en ces moments elle se laissait aller à une apparente rêverie, si ce n'était plutôt une intense contemplation. (personne normale, user **LPH**)

**2/** On dit « se rappeler de » par analogie avec « se souvenir de » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rappeler)), mais cette explication n'est pas claire;

> (TLFi)  [P. anal. avec se souvenir de] Se rappeler de, s'en rappeler.
>
> - Mais je ne me rappelle pas de vous (...). Qu'y a-t-il pour votre service?.
> - C'est vrai, dit le père Chapdelaine, je me rappelle de ce temps-là. Il n'y avait pas une seule maison en haut du lac : rien que des sauvages et quelques chasseurs.

Il faut de toute façon se rappeler que l'usage de « de » n'est pas limité aux pronoms lorsque l'on s'intéresse à la littérature (voir exemple ci-dessus); cela est clairement établi dans ce qui suit.

Les explications concernant la prescription à propos de la préposition sont les plus  claires et succinctes dans la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2881);

> (BDL) […], lorsque le complément est un pronom personnel de la première ou de la deuxième personne, il est permis de transgresser la règle et d’employer la préposition « de » (« Je me rappelle de vous. » et non « Je me vous rappelle. »), même si certains grammairiens recommandent d’employer dans ce cas le verbe « se souvenir ».
>
> Exemples :
>
> - Je me rappelle très bien de lui. (ou : Je me souviens très bien de lui.)
> - Quand je l’ai revue, elle ne se rappelait plus de moi. (ou : elle ne se souvenait plus de moi)
>
> En conclusion, même si « se rappeler de », sur le modèle de « se souvenir de », est bien attesté depuis le XVIIIe siècle, autant chez les grands auteurs que dans la langue générale, les grammairiens, bien qu’ils soient unanimes à constater que cet emploi est très répandu, se montrent encore réticents à admettre cette construction, et force nous est de devoir encore nous plier à ces règles si nous voulons nous conformer à la norme grammaticale.

**3/** On doit aussi ne pas considérer que l'utilisation du verbe avaec la préposition « de » lorsque un pronom est utilisé soit la seule possible, exclusive de l'utilisation normale sans préposition ; celle-ci est encore possible ;

- Je me rappelle d'elle. *ou* Je me la rappelle. ([Nouveau dictionnaire de langue française](https://books.google.fr/books?id=waJHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA847&dq=%22je+me+la+rappelle%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj9-LnlKbjAhUJ7eAKHRNUATEQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=%22je%20me%20la%20rappelle%22&f=false))

  autres références : [ref1](https://books.google.fr/books?id=xylnAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA66&dq=%22je+me+la+rappelle%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj9-LnlKbjAhUJ7eAKHRNUATEQ6AEIQzAF#v=onepage&q=%22je%20me%20la%20rappelle%22&f=false), [ref2](https://books.google.fr/books?id=hC8tBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT45&dq=%22je+me+la+rappelle%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIqYarl6bjAhVt5OAKHXYoDS04FBDoAQg9MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22je%20me%20la%20rappelle%22&f=false), [ref3](https://books.google.fr/books?id=hEwoMwvPmdEC&pg=PA80&dq=%22je+me+la+rappelle%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji_PqnmKbjAhV55OAKHUPCCPM4MhDoAQgnMAA#v=onepage&q=%22je%20me%20la%20rappelle%22&f=false).

L'Ac. est encore plus stricte car elle considère aussi comme fautif l'emploi de la préposition avec les pronoms ([Ac.](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/se-rappeler-quelque-chose-se-souvenir-de-quelque-chose) : « […] erreur […] particulièrement frappante lorsque le complément est un pronom).

**II** Se souvenir

**1/**

> (TLFi) Qqn/qqc. se souvient de qqc./qqn/que. Avoir, garder, se remettre en mémoire. Synon. se rappeler (v. ce mot III), se ressouvenir.
>
> (TLFi) (état) Avoir présent à l'esprit, avoir en mémoire quelque chose; avoir gardé le souvenir de quelque chose. Anton. oublier.
>
> (TLFi) (action) Se remettre en mémoire; faire ressurgir, retrouver le souvenir de quelque chose. Synon. se remémorer.

Donc d'après ces définitions, chaque variante de « se rappeler qqc » a pour synonyme « se souvenir de qqc ».

**2/** la forme avec « en » est aussi utilisée dans la littérature passée et présente pour les animés : [ref1](https://books.google.fr/books?id=zvY_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA321&dq=%22je+m%27en+souviens%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6zPaYmqbjAhUORBoKHa03B1E4ChDoAQhKMAY#v=onepage&q=%22je%20m'en%20souviens%22&f=false), [ref2](https://books.google.fr/books?id=uJaFQYdhRXQC&pg=PT117&dq=%22je+m%27en+souviens%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhr62tnKbjAhVuzoUKHcAfDiI4KBDoAQhEMAU#v=onepage&q=%22je%20m'en%20souviens%22&f=false), [ref3](https://books.google.fr/books?id=tsLST9uOJ1cC&pg=PA21&dq=%22je+m%27en+souviens%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhr62tnKbjAhVuzoUKHcAfDiI4KBDoAQhbMAk#v=onepage&q=%22je%20m'en%20souviens%22&f=false), [ref4](https://books.google.fr/books?id=0GU8AGmI-c4C&pg=PT153&dq=%22je+m%27en+souviens%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWl77znabjAhUNzYUKHf8vC804MhDoAQgnMAA#v=onepage&q=%22je%20m'en%20souviens%22&f=false), [ref5](https://books.google.fr/books?id=rR6JAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT7&dq=%22je+m%27en+souviens%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjyrIDenqbjAhXIyYUKHabHDK44PBDoAQgtMAE#v=onepage&q=%22je%20m'en%20souviens%22&f=false), [ref6](https://books.google.fr/books?id=_TZMAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA28&dq=%22je+m%27en+souviens%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisyJaqn6bjAhVSx4UKHXIpAvE4RhDoAQhXMAg#v=onepage&q=%22je%20m'en%20souviens%22&f=false), [ref7](https://books.google.fr/books?id=TTrYAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT316&dq=%22je+m%27en+souviens%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip6pnmn6bjAhVMxYUKHQQoByk4UBDoAQg9MAM#v=onepage&q=%22je%20m'en%20souviens%22&f=false), [ref8](https://books.google.fr/books?id=fbYgBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT133&dq=%22je+m%27en+souviens%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF1KWzoKbjAhUO4BoKHYXbDvU4WhDoAQgyMAI#v=onepage&q=%22je%20m'en%20souviens%22&f=false). Il n'est pas correct d'affirmer qu'elle est spécialisée aux « non neutres ».

**III**

**1/** Il n'y a pas d'évidence d'une différence particulière de sens entre « se rappeler qqc » et « se souvenir de qqc », bien que certaines personnes tendent à en voir une. On trouve une certaine évidence de cela dans ces [discussions](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/se-souvenir-de-se-rappeler-diff%c3%a9rence-de-sens.783689/) et dans [celles-ci](https://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070202124616AAuisXv&guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYmluZy5jb20vc2VhcmNoP3E9c2Urc291dmVuaXIrc2UrcmFwcGVsZXIrZGlmZiVjMyVhOXJlbmNlJmZpcnN0PTExJkZPUk09UE9SRQ&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAJCrQrK80l8BYAhLPXIiziZ--y5KiH0o2Ofow41fFKQNWBsAbzlB8D5zblD81USSC0vrIpgzUutHOWcZ0Hg4i2_ViTW1HRDHFlKXs-voEDg5zVJVanPV7AxQdJuOLkCVm47SS9TLxNB5cdWzWm6330L3hcqY4wAmOxCvfGbk-MAJ) mais  dans les dictionnaires il n'est pas question d'autre chose que de stricte synonymie.

Answer (score 0):

Les 2 phrases suivantes sont tout à fait correctes:

> Je me rappelle **des** vacances au bord de la mer
>
> Je me rappelle **les** vacances au bord de la mer, j'avais 6 ou 7 ans

seulement la première phrase (avec "**des**") sous-entend que vous n'avez été qu'une seule fois en vacances au bord de la mer.

Le deuxième cas (avec "**les**") indique que vous ayez été plusieurs fois en vacances aux bords de la mer et implique que vous donniez plus de précision dans la suite de la phrase pour que votre interlocuteur vous comprenne. Sans précision supplémentaires, l'interlocuteur vous demandera certainement "**lesquelles?**"